# Sencha touch testing with Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, testing, mobile, sencha-touch

We often test a Sencha Touch app in Chrome, and although the behaviour is not a problem, the visual display is.

What **Overrides settings** in Chrome's Developer Tools do I need to use to reproduce what it would look like an iOS or Android device?  My focus here is on the font and rendering.

**Edit:**  Here are two examples.  The first is takes from iOS, and the second is from Chrome.  Of course the sizes are different, but besides the sizes, you can see that the one in chrome is not rendering well.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you explain what kind of differences you see in chrome?

Comment: @ThinkFloyd examples added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem for this has nothing to do with Crome or Sencha Touch.  It is the Mac OS "LCD font smoothing" that caused all the issues.

Go to `System Preferances > General > Use LCD font smoothing when available` and disable it. Restart Chrome, and everything is much better.